# win something 'as' a prize?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, spoken-english

How do you describe this situation: "**My mom entered for a prize drawing, won it, and got a bag.**"?

Which is more natural as an expression in spoken English?

- "She won a bag **as** a prize"
- "She won a bag **by** a prize"

Or some other way?

Comment: She won a bag *as* a prize.

Comment: I have never heard of the construction 'by a prize' - where have you seen that?

Comment: Were you looking for, "My mom obtained that bag by way of a prize."?

Comment: By the way, it's 'a prize draw'. A drawing is a kind of picture.

Comment: @KateBunting I have no problem with using *drawing* for an act of choosing by lots, and neither does [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drawing)....

Comment: You also don't "apply" for such things. You "enter" them or "enter your name" in them.

Comment: You could say that it's a **prize bag**. Ever heard of **prize money** or **prize car**?

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't clear from the other comment, "She won a bag as a prize." is the correct sentence.

You could also say: "She won a bag" (implying it was a prize). "She won a prize bag." (Though this could be confused as there was a bag with several prizes in it.)

But the original "She won a bag as a prize," is the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

My mom was entered in a prize drawing and won a bag (sense that someone bought the ticket for her).

My mom bought a ticket for a prize drawing, won it, and got a bag. (won a bag as the prize).

My mom won a bag in a prize drawing.